# access code from an example demo PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, components, demo

I want to see the code of this demo of component PrimeFaces: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/layout/mailbox.xhtml
when I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on primefaces svn repository

https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/ui/panel/layout/mailbox.xhtml

Comment: thank you for your fast response, the java code is  in the same svn repository ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the java code:
https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/view/panel/MailboxView.java

And the Facelet code:
https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/ui/panel/layout/mailbox.xhtml